# window.open(,name) that name pass not working?

Tags: javascript, html

```
s = document.getElementById("name");
```

it is not generating `name` of this code:

```
winref = window.open("home/login.aspx",s,strFeatures);
```

It says "invalid argument".

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a reference to a DOM node as the name of the new window. That's not going to work in IE, which insists that a window name be a valid identifier, not just any old string. (I'm not 100% sure that internally  the DOM node would be converted to a string via ".toString()" or equivalent, but it probably would.)

Perhaps you meant to get some attribute or property value from the node you found:

```
var winref = window.open("home/login.aspx", s.something, strFeatures);
```

Also, don't forget `var` on your variable declarations!